# How to perform cross addition on an image in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv

i am reading a tutorial and there is an equation as shown in the image. I know that sign in the image called cross addition, but my question is is there any method in opencv that performs cross addition?[image: here]

Comment: I'm probably just ignorant, but I have no idea what "cross addition" is, and apparently neither does google.

Comment: What the heck is with all of the white space?

Comment: @rayryeng he image is just big

Comment: OK that's fine.. So what's this cross addition that you're wanting to know about? None of us know what it is. Can you show us this tutorial on where you found it?

Answer (score 1):

This 'plus in a circle' in this context most likely refers to [Direct addition of Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_addition)

In particular, the unary notation ⊕I<sub>1..n</sub> refers to the construction of a diagonalised matrix of the matrices I.

For example, suppose we have:

[image]

There is no single method in OpenCV that performs this but you can easily use existing matrix operations to do it by:

1. Create output matrix of correct size and init with zeros
2. Iterate over matrices to be direct added and set appropriate esubrange of output matrix